# Unexpected behavour of XmlSerializer

Tags: c#

I have a `Child` inherited from `List<string>`. I have two parent classes containing `Children`, one as list, another as an array. The `XmlSerializer` initialization works well for the one who have Children as List and fails for second one with NullReference exception. I need `Parent2` serialized with an array of `Child`s. Am I missing something?

```
void Main()
{
    XmlSerializer serParent1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Parent1)); // works well
    XmlSerializer serParent2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Parent2)); // fails
}

public class Parent1
{
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Parent2
{
    public Child[] Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child : List<string>
{
}
```

Comment: The code is failing because the instance you are using to serialize is null.  The code posted look fine.  The only thing wrong is the Child class has no properties.  You need to add at least one property to Child.

Comment: @jdweng which instance? I can't even create initializer in line #2.

Comment: Use following for child :    public class Child
    {
        public string[] text { get; set; }
    }

Comment: @jdweng I know a number of workatounds, but simply why doesn't that one work? I specially simplified my case to those classes only to show issue

Comment: Is it not a case that Child[] is not nullable?

Comment: Because you do not have any properties.  What property names would you use the get the values?

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood I'm not serializing any object, I'm creating a serializer for specific object type.

Comment: @jdweng I'm not really following you. Why initializer for Parent1 works and doesn't for Parent2? They're almost same, the only difference is List<Child> vs Child[]. Adding a property to Child won't help, of course.

Comment: They are not the same.  An array is an older version of c language that has limited capabilities.   A list is an enhancement of standard c language that has more capabilities.  So you cannot just say an array is almost a list.  They are two different animals.  It is like saying a Donkey is almost a Horse.

Comment: @jdweng I still have no clue why XmlSerializer fails with that undescriptive error. Adding property to Child doesn't solve the issue. Moreover, I can instantiate XmlInitializer for the Child with no properties, but not for Parent2.

Comment: Lost of Microsoft errors an undescriptive.  You are dealing with the way the Xml Serializer library handles arrays verses list.  You can't fix a microsoft library, just learn to live with the anomaly.

Comment: @LINQ2Vodka, this isn't a solution for you, but I can replicate the error and the stacktrace is "deep" into the serialization namespace, far from the constructor. I think you may of come across a .net bug.

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood thank you for help. I am really surprised to have such specific bug after a century of .NET :)

Comment: @jdweng The question is about C#. C is irrelevant.

Comment: What is relevant is an Array and a List are not the same.  Array go back to c language while lists are enhanced versions or Arrays and are newer.